# Redmine 3.3.0, Global Statistics Plugin on Postgresql

Tags: ruby, postgresql, redmine, redmine-plugins

Hello i've installed Redmine 3.3.0 for my company, everything was going great but [Global Stats](https://github.com/luisfontes19/redmine_stats) created some problems.

These are what info i've gathered so far :

Plugin doesn't work with Postgresql no matter what Redmine version you are on *if* you've at least one issue in any project.

It works completely well with mySQL on any Redmine version.

I have little knowledge on Ruby and SQL so this might look like a homework question but bear with me.

This is Redmine production.log error when i want to access Statistics page (again if there is at least one issue created)

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=):
  app/models/project.rb:310:in `find'
  plugins/redmine_stats/app/models/stat.rb:64:in `block in authors'
  plugins/redmine_stats/app/models/stat.rb:63:in `each'
  plugins/redmine_stats/app/models/stat.rb:63:in `authors'
  plugins/redmine_stats/app/controllers/stats_controller.rb:22:in `index'
  lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

The problem is i think how the plugin handles postgresql queries (shocking, i know.) This code below is from stat.rb where Redmine log gives error.

```
#get all authors of issues
def self.authors(project)

return project.authors unless project == nil

data = []

if project.nil?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT count(project_id), project_id from issues group by project_id  order by count(project_id) DESC LIMIT 5").each do |row|
                data << Project.find(row[0])
        end
else

        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT count(author_id), author_id from issues where project_id = '#{project.id}' group by author_id  order by count(author_id) DESC LIMIT 5").each do |row|
                data << User.find(row[0])
        end
    end

    data

end
```

Finally this is my Redmine environment on localhost (completely same with the live version on company servers)

```
Environment:
Redmine version                3.3.0.stable
Ruby version                   2.3.0-p0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  4.2.6
Environment                    production
Database adapter               PostgreSQL
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.8
  Git                            1.9.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_stats                  0.0.3
```

I've posted this question on both Redmine official forums and the plugin author's github page but no answers for at least 1 month. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add these strings to \config\additional_environment.rb:

```
config.logger = Logger.new('log/logfile.log', 2, 1000000)
config.log_level = :debug
```

and check queries in that log when page is loaded.
Copy them to any IDE with support of postgres databases and test if any result returned

Answer (score 0):

Try this fork with claims to fix PostgreSQL support:

https://github.com/myaspm/redmine_stats_2

Comment: Yeah after i couldnt find a solution, i changed the original plugin a bit and published it under Redmine Stats 2 name. It works so far. Glad to see that it finds its own way to me again :D

Comment: Haha... Internet wins today. I was looking for a stats plugin and found your repo and this issue :D. You could add a PR to the original repo.